# Existence of elements of order $2$ in $S_n$ whose Product has order $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

> Show that all for $n>2$, $S_n$ contains two elements $x,y$, both of order $2$, such that their product is of order $n$.

I can find such elements for $n$ small, but I don't know how to make up an algorithm to produce these $x,y$ for large $n$. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Think about a regular polygon.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That's the best hint I've seen for a long time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the dihedral group as a subgroup of the symmetric group with $s$ the reflection and $r$ the rotation generators. Then the elements $sr$ and $sr^2$ each have order $2$ and their product is $r$ which has order $n$. Note that we've tacitly used that $n > 2$.

Comment: So, formally speaking, I should first consider the case $n=3$ separately and then say that for $k\ge 2$, $D_k$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{2k}$ by Cayley's theorem?

Comment: @user437307 yes you can either invoke Cayley's Theorem to claim it is a subgroup or you can choose a cycle of length $n$, label the vertices of an $n$-gon using that cycle and then see how the reflection permutes the vertices to figure out it's representation, or even use $2 \times 2$ rotation matrices with a reflection matrix to generate the group explicitly.

Also, recall that $S_3 \cong D_3$ so you don't need to do that case separately. All you need is that $1,sr$ and $sr^2$ are distinct elements from from each other which first happens when $n=3$.

Answer (score 2):

One pattern that works for $n=2k+1$ is $$(2\,3)(4\,5)\ldots(2k\,2k+1)\circ(1\,2)(3\,4)(5\,6)\cdots(2k-1\,2k) 
=(1\,3\,5\,7\,\ldots\, 2k-1\,2k+1\,2k\,2k-2\,\ldots\,6\,4\,2)$$
and a similar pattren for $n=2k$.

Answer (score 1):

Two reflections (generally) make a rotation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For $n= 3$, we note that 
$$ (1\ 3 ) (2\ 3) = (1\  2\ 3), $$
and 
$$ \big| (1 \ 2) \big| = 2 = \big| (2 \ 3) \big|, $$
whereas 
$$ \big| (1 \ 2 \ 3) \big| = 3. $$

For $n=4$, we find that 
$$ \big[ (1 \ 2) ( 3\ 4) \big] \big[ ( 1 \ 3)  \big] = ( 1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4 ),   $$
and 
$$ \big|  (1 \ 2) ( 3\ 4)  \big| = 2 = \big| (1 \ 3) \big|, $$
whereas 
$$ \big| (1 \ 2\ 3 \ 4) \big| = 4. $$

For $n= 5$, we find that 
$$ \big[ (1 \ 2) ( 3 \ 5) \big] \big[ (1 \ 3) ( 4\ 5)  \big] = (1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4 \ 5), $$
and 
$$ \big|  (1 \ 2) ( 3 \ 5) \big| = 2 = \big| (1 \ 3) ( 4\ 5)  \big|, $$
whereas 
$$ \big| (1 \ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5) \big| = 5. $$

Hope this helps.